# Exceeding warning level for storage after adding site collection to larger template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, alert, storage

I keep receiving the following warning email after expanding the site quota.

> You are receiving this e-mail message because you are an administrator
>   of the following SharePoint Web site, which has exceeded the warning
>   level for storage: http://sharepoint/. To see how much
>   storage is being taken up by this site, go to the View site collection
>   usage summary: http://sharepoint/_layouts/Usage.aspx.

When I view `http://sharepoint/_layouts/Usage.aspx` the page contains no data.

To remedy the error I create a new Site Quota Template with:

> Name: Extra Large Collaboration Portal
>
> Max Storage: 200000MB
>
> Warning Email: 180000MB

I assigned the template to the Site Collection.

I've confirmed in the Site Collection Quota and Locks that the template is indeed being used and the current storage is at 139533MB.

Even though my current storage is roughly 40 GB away from the warning level. I still keep receive the warning email.

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Site Collection Quota and Locks
[image]

Comment: what you see if you go to the Site collection quota and Locks from central admin?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I added a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Timer Job named "Disk quota warning" which defaults schedule is to run weekly. Since the last run, you will continue to receive these e-mails until the Disk quota warning-timer job runs again. To get rid of these email, navigate to Central Admin > Monitoring > Timer Job Definitions to find this timer job, and click on the Run Now-button. If your quota level is outside of the scope of when to send warning e-mails, they won't be sent again.

*If you only have one content database to your almost 200 GB of content, it's time to plan for a second one and move site collections to the new content database.*

Reference: [Timer Job reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870.aspx)

Comment: I've changed the template a little over a week and a half ago

Comment: @zingwing Have you forced run of the timer job

Comment: It last run on 5/16/2015 and the site quota was changed on 5/1/2015. I'm not sure it's the timer.